# Magento 2.4.5 "Page builder was rendering for 5 seconds without releasing locks"

Tags: magento2

When I try to save a product in the Magento admin panel, the page stays on the saving screen. In the Javascript console, I see an error with "Page builder was rendering for 5 seconds without releasing locks". This seems to only occur when multiple instances of the pagebuilder are loaded on a single page. I've tried saving on other pages with just one pagebuilder instance, and saving works correctly. Any advice? This is on 2.4.5 Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Are you using Cloudflare, maybe? I'm running into the same issue with multiple editors on a page, but I'm starting to think it is because of cloudflare, because I cannot reproduce the error on my dev server..

Comment: I have issues in my local environment as well which using ubuntu+docker

Comment: I found a workaround that seems to work so far for me, which is basically to disable the check that throws this error; vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/form-mixin.js in the "else" statement, also put submit() on top, comment the rest. In my testing so far it saves the data every time.